# Ubuntu not booting up in virtual Box

Tags: boot, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed virtual box in MacOs. I am currently running ubuntu 18.04 on it. But it is not booting up. it gets stuck after showing the below image.
[This is  what is displays.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eve4.png)
I have also tried installing the latest version of virtual box, but still this error persists.